# imported google icons not sit in the baseline with its sibling text

Tags: css

i am trying to import few google icons to make my navigation bar look bit nicer, but i found the icons its not sitting in the same baseline with its siblings text which its pretty annoying, and my solution was:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>home</span></a>
</ul>
```

the `<i>`tag here it illustrates the icon of the home page and i made a `<span>`tag with "home"text to sit next to it. but i found the baseline between the icon and text are not in the same line. therefore, my solution was making the `span`tag to be absolute and give it size with 22px(icon size was 24*24) but it still not looks really satisfied.

So my question is: is there any other elegant way to make this icon and text to sit in the same baseline?

Comment: i did, but it still falling below the icon a bit, so i am calling position:absolute to modify the top/bottom properties of the span text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  `vertical-align` for `i`, for same baseline as the text and remove absolute position from span

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a span {
  font-size: 22px;
}
a i {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="main-nav">
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span>Home</span></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the `margin-top`/`margin-bottom` for `i`, to make it be the same baseline as the text.

Comment: then i have to call the <i> tag position as "absolute" here if setting top/bot margin on it?